nsExec:: not working with console application?
i am currently writing an nsis installer and i need the console output of a console application which get started by the installer.
When the nsExec::ExecToStack gets executed i get an cryptic error message (probably a number but wrong encoding)
This is the nsExec code:
nsExec::ExecToStack $TEMP\myexe.exe HandleOldMDBS
    Pop $0 # return value/error/timeout
    Pop $1 # printed text, up to ${NSIS_MAX_STRLEN}
    MessageBox MB_OK|MB_ICONINFORMATION "Console Output: $1 Return value: $0"
    DetailPrint "Console Output: $1"
    DetailPrint "Return value: $0"

The console application is compiled in .Net Framework 4.7.2 and Any CPU

I would expect the dialog to contain the return code of the application which would be 0 in this case

ASCII/ANSI text interpreted as UTF-16 often looks like Chinese text. Use /MBCS or /OEM to force nsExec to interpret stdout as ANSI.
nsExec::ExecToStack /MBCS '"$TEMP\MDBS\MDBS.Helper.exe" HandleOldMDBS'
Pop $0
Pop $1


Thank you for your response. Unfortunately this did not improve the output. But i am now using ExecWait and will write the output to a text file instead of returning it to NSIS.

Can you find an application that is included with Windows that reproduces the output issue?
